# How to save edits in wordpress after debugging a styling issue with devtool?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Last 5 submenu icons are not showing http://newlayouthomepage1.bluebirdpackaging.com/ . In mega menu wordpress is unable to save the settings for the icons. So I just tried to add them up through dev tool. Now the problem is how do I save these edits.

I added this `<i class="im-icon-arrow-right-2"></i>` and changed `class="item_link  disable_icon" tabindex="44">` to `class="item_link  with_icon" tabindex="44">` to show the submenu icon

`<a href="http://newlayouthomepage1.bluebirdpackaging.com/product-category/custom-printed-apparel-packaging-boxes-wholesale/" class="item_link  disable_icon" tabindex="44">
                <span class="link_content">
                    <span class="link_text">
                        Apparel Boxes
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>`

The result I am looking for is to save the html edits I do from dev tool to make them permanent.

Comment: Are you getting any error while saving the settings? Can you rephrase your question so we could understand and propose a solution?

Comment: nope not getting any errors. When I click on save and check the settings the icons are not there. it just resets to default . Maybe there is a way to add the arrows from css ?

Comment: I think the real issue is in your server PHP settings. Do you have access to the server PHP settings?

Comment: Yes , I have access to php files through wordpress. @KashifRafique

Comment: Not php files. You need to change the PHP settings either through hosting panel or through php.ini/.htaccess files. You can't do any of the two from WordPress. You need hosting panel access.